# How to use both audio output and audio input at Openframeworks in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, openframeworks

I'm trying to make an audio app for iOS with Openframeworks. The app needs both playing audio output and microphone input. It is OK if they don't work together in same time but work turn by turn.

I had 2 ideas but they did not meet my demand.

[A]Switch them with like `ofSoundStreamSetup(2, 0, this, sampleRate, initialBufferSize, 4);` for  output and `ofSoundStreamSetup(0, 1, this, sampleRate, initialBufferSize, 4);` for output.
This makes memory problem and the app is down when ofSoundStreamSetup() and ofSoundClose() is called. I guess ofSoundStream can't be closed because audioReceived() is working always. It seems there is no way to close them once the microphone input is activated.

[B]Enable Both output and input channels with like `ofSoundStreamSetup(2, 1, this, sampleRate, initialBufferSize, 4);`.
This is OK. The app did not down. But speaker output and earphone output of L-ch are heard smaller than[A] (with my iPhone4S).

Could you help if having good ideas?

Comment: Your [B] would be the correct option. If one channel is quieter than the other, it sounds like it might just be an issue with panning?

Comment: You could take a look at libpd as well ?

Comment: Thank you all, I can solve partially and I have to apologize that my question was not accurate.

I believe your advice that [B] must be correct. and I checked the phenomenon again. L-R balance was not equal in my iPhone with default iPod music player so this is not bug of my app. But the problem that the volume is smaller when I use both Input and Output, is left. Then I noticed that speaker is changed. If use only output the sound is out from speaker in bottom of the speaker (near mic), but use both input and output sound is out from the speaker for ear when you call.

Comment: These are codes to use bottom speaker. If set this at first of my program, it makes noises but just before track playing it works well.

    UInt32 overrideAudioRoute = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                            sizeof(overrideAudioRoute),
                            &overrideAudioRoute);